# Combined Redux reducers with different instance of the same component

Tags: react-native, redux

I have two views implemented with React Native called authentication and main. Each of this view, contains separate instance of shared keyboard component and simple text view for displaying typed from keyboard text. State of these views is maintained by Redux in a simple format:

```
authentication : {
   keyboard : {
       value : ""
   }
}
main {
   keyboard : {
       value : ""
   }
}
```

Reducers are implemented as follows:

```
let main = combineReducers( { keyboard: keyboard } );
let authenticate = combineReducers( { keyboard: keyboard } );
let combinedReducers = combineReducers( {
   main,
   authenticate
 } );
```

Keyboard's reducer based of received action appends or removes characters to value. And now here comes the magic, I don't get it why the value is updated twice, both in authentication & main parts. Even if the keyboard component is a separate instance of connected container ?! I assume that there something need to be combined with reducers but it is tricky to imagine what exactly....

Answer (score 0):

The `combineReducers` function automatically passes a given chunk of state to the reducer function at that key, along with the current action.  In addition, it looks like you're using the same "keyboard" reducer function in two places.  That means that if you dispatch a particular action, both uses of the "keyboard" reducer will get called, both will see some state + this action, and both will respond.  It's just a matter of the same function being called twice because it's being hooked up twice.